Minesweeper constructions in combinatorics
In a related question I asked if constructions based on Sudoku puzzles could be used to obtain any deep results in combinatorics and noted that there were papers of Greenfeld and Tao where Sudoku constructions where employed to resolve several open problems for higher-dimensional tilings.
In the article ''Undecidability of translational monotilings'', they also have a ''Tetris move'', which happens when a row is completely filled out and deleted.
I was wondering if there any combinatorial proofs where ''Minesweeper'' moves or constructions can be used in a non-trivial way.  Obivously, there is a long list of papers on the mathematics of minesweeper from the viewpoint of combinatorics and complexity, but I am more specifically looking for useful constructions in proofs which resemble Minesweeper.
For those not familiar, in the game Minesweeper each cell on the grid which is filled with a symbol gives information about nearby cells, making it progressively easier to fill the square.  This is different to the Sudoku construction where one has constraints that each symbol has to appear exactly once in each row, each column, each subgrid, and so on.
